# How can I force Ninject to exception when largest constructor has unresolvable dependencies?

Tags: c#, ninject

According to the documentation for Ninject:

> The primary DI pattern is Constructor Injection. When activating an instance of a type Ninject will choose one of the type’s constructors to use by applying the following rules in order:-
>
> 1. If a constructor has an [Inject] attribute, it is used (but if you apply the attribute to more than one, Ninject will throw a NotSupportedException at runtime upon detection).
> 2. If no constructors have an [Inject] attribute, Ninject will select the one with the most parameters that Ninject understands how to resolve.
> 3. If no constructors are defined, Ninject will select the default parameterless constructor (assuming there is one).

It seems there is a gotcha in #2 that is hard to miss if you glance at this list quickly.  The gotcha is in the `that Ninject understands how to resolve`.

Consider the following scenario:

```
// Defined in MyController.cs
public void MyController(IMyDependency depencency) { }

// Defined in MyController.generated.cs for T4
public void MyController() { }
```

If Ninject has not had any types bound to `IMyDependency` and then you call `kernel.Resolve<MyController>()`, it will *not* exception but instead pass, using the parameterless constructor instead.

However, this is most definitely *NOT* desired behavior as I want to be notified of resolution failings immediately, and the default Ninject functionality also makes it impossible to test IOC resolutions in coded tests.

Is there any way to have Ninject exception if resolution fails on the constructor with the most parameters and not fall back to other constructors if possible?

Comment: If the class "cannot" (should not) be instanciated using that constructor, why is it there in the first place? That seems like faulty design to me. Ninject's nice enough to allow you to modify the constructor selection to accommodate you for your specific use case but I for one am very glad it doesn't work like you'd like it to *by default*.

Comment: Because auto-generated code doesn't know that it never needs to be called, it just knows what it needs to create to facilitate it's generated purpose.  In this instance it needs it in order to generate the MVC helpers to give non-magic string view links in MVC views.  Not everything is always 100% in your control, but the Ninject default assumes you meant to have that there.

Comment: Yes which is perfectly fine b/c when you hit that suboptimal case it allows you to override it's behavior and choose something more appropriate for your case. Your post reads like a rant on Ninject and i think your wrong b/c the *default* case is good for most use cases. I fully appreciate that in your case you *need* to adapt ninject's behavior but i don't think it's a justification for ranting ;-)

Comment: I was actually under the impression most other IoC frameworks (Unity and Windsor) don't work like this but always choose the highest unless otherwise attributed, though in now researching I don't see them specify what it does if the largest constructor does not have resolvable parameters.  I don't really have the time to test them all out at the moment though, so I'll just work under the assuumption that I was wrong and they would all work like Ninject in this scenarioi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your own `IConstructorScorer`, probably by subclassing the default `StandardConstructorScorer` and giving low scores to constructors that you don't like the look of...

> Ninject runs each constructor through the IConstructorScorer interface to determine which constructor it should use to instantiate the class

Details of how to do this are in the [documentation on github](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Component-Extension-Points#iconstructorscorer).

In your case, it might look something like this:

```
public class MyScorer : StandardConstructorScorer
{
    public override int Score(IContext context, ConstructorInjectionDirective directive)
    {
        //has more than one constructor
        //and the constructor being considered is parameterless
        if (directive.Constructor.GetType().GetConstructors().Count() > 1 
            && !directive.Targets.Any())
        {
            //give it a low score
            return Int32.MinValue;
        }
        return base.Score(context, directive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, reading your question again, I think perhaps an [ISelector](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Component-Extension-Points#iselector) might be more appropriate. You should take an in depth look at the entire page as there are many extensibility points mentioned that allow you to change the default behaviour of ninject.

Comment: Stupid question, but how do you give the ISelector or ConstructorScorer to the Ninject kernel to use?  I can't find any documentation on how to do that and it's not picking it up automatically.  Otherwise this looks exactly like what I need

Comment: Aha got it.  I created a new implementation of kernelBase that added my selector as a component, and all is now good with the world :)